# Is the hashcode of a Java String created when the String is created, or only at the first call for hashcode?

Tags: java, string

My question is quite simple.

When is the hashcode for a String calculated?

1. When the String is created, the hashcode is also computed, and always ready in O(1) after construction
2. The hashcode is computed only the first time the `hashCode` method is called and is ready in O(1) time for all subsequent calls
3. The hashcode is computed each time the `hashCode` method is called

Option 1 seems reasonable because Strings are immutable. The hashcode for a given string will never change. But, this slows down the creation of strings, so it also seems reasonable that option 2 would be used. Option 3 seems silly and a waste of time, but saves on space because the hashcode isn't being stored. There may also be some logical reason that Option 3 is the best approach that I'm not thinking about.

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: [Option 2.](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#l1452)

Comment: @khelwood Really? The hash code of a String object is somehow cached after calling hashCode? Cached where? In the object? I think it's Option 3

Comment: @ControlAltDel In a private field inside the String class. In fact if you check `String.class.getDeclaredFields()`, you can see a private int called `hash`.

Comment: You can look at the source code for `String` and see that it's computed and cached on first call. *\*How\** this works with immutability is a different story, one best left to experts.  The short answer is that it kinda doesn't; if two threads call `hashCode()` close together in time there's a pretty fair chance both will end up separately calculating hash code's value.  This works because the string characters never change, so the same hash code will always be computed.

Comment: @khelwood I learned something today :)

Comment: Explaining Java's thread model, including immutability, in a short comment like this is pretty much impossible.  If you want the full story, I think the best option is to get Brian Goetz's book *Java Concurrency in Practice.*  It has the nitty gritty, and also imo is supremely clearly written.

Comment: Note that _Java `String`s' hash codes_ aren't calculated at any of these points; they just _happen_. The fact that (2) is used by OpenJDK is an implementation detail.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I'm not sure what you mean by that.  If you mean "the caching behavior of hashCode is not externally specified," yes that's fair.  Its current implementation could change if desired.  However, in Java's 25 year plus history, `hashCode` has always been calculated like this.

Comment: @markspace I mean that there's no such thing as the "Java" behavior, only the behavior of certain implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 2. It's calculated the first time `hashCode` is called and stored in a private field.

In OpenJDK 8 it looks like this:

```
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0 && value.length > 0) {
        char val[] = value;

        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            h = 31 * h + val[i];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#l1452

In fact, if you take a look at what fields String has, you can see it has a private int called `hash`.

```
System.out.println(String.class.getDeclaredFields());
```

output includes

```
{ ... private int java.lang.String.hash ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

From the source code JDK 14

```
   /** Cache the hash code for the string */
    private int hash; // Default to 0


    @HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate
    public String(String original) {
        this.value = original.value;
        this.coder = original.coder;
        this.hash = original.hash;
    }
```

And then

```
    public int hashCode() {
        // The hash or hashIsZero fields are subject to a benign data race,
        // making it crucial to ensure that any observable result of the
        // calculation in this method stays correct under any possible read of
        // these fields. Necessary restrictions to allow this to be correct
        // without explicit memory fences or similar concurrency primitives is
        // that we can ever only write to one of these two fields for a given
        // String instance, and that the computation is idempotent and derived
        // from immutable state
        int h = hash;
        if (h == 0 && !hashIsZero) {
            h = isLatin1() ? StringLatin1.hashCode(value)
                           : StringUTF16.hashCode(value);
            if (h == 0) {
                hashIsZero = true;
            } else {
                hash = h;
            }
        }
        return h;
    }
```